# Find classes that have included a particular concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just created a Concern called Statable, which is included in several different Models. It would be cool if my StatsController#index could just automatically loop through all of the models that have included Statable. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "Statable" ? Do you mean "Stateable" or "Statisticsable" or "Statusable" or ?

Comment: lol. If I have to chose from your options, I'll go with Statisticsable, but that's too many letters to type.